# Insert a video on Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flv

Hi I'm trying to put a FLV video into a flash adobe CC actionscript project and it gives me an error like this one when I try to get to the corresponding photogram:

> Error #2044: Unhandled skinError:. text=[SecurityErrorEvent
>   type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2
>   text="Error #2140: Security sandbox violation:
>   file:///C|/Users/Gael/Desktop/pfc/proxecto.swf cannot load
>   file:///C|/Users/Gael/Desktop/pfc/SkinOverAllNoVolNoCaptionNoFull.swf.
>   Local-with-filesystem and local-with-networking SWF files cannot load
>   each other."]

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not caused by flv video. It is caused by the player skin SkinOverAllNoVolNoCaptionNoFull.swf compiled with security sandbox type other than security sandbox type of your application.

You need to change Security sandbox type of your proxecto.swf application.
You can configure a SWF file for the local-with-networking sandbox by setting the document’s publish settings in the authoring tool.